# The package "apppxbundle" is taking a long time to process. Unable to push update to windows store [UWP] [ Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I've been at this for past 2 days and I'm getting weird errors from the store.

I'm trying to upload an update to my application "CoManga" via the store and it's not working out.

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms (UWP) and before making the appxbundle, I made sure and "associated my app with  CoManga" from my developer account. All the information over there matches and should work fine without any issues.

Then I made a release of my UWP app, got the bundle and I tried to upload it to UWP.
It said that the Publisher info is different, so it couldn't upload. This is weird because I tried signing the bundle with my developer account itself.

Now, I tried building and signing the app bundle from app center. I got the appxbundle and that I tried to upload. But, since today it's giving me weird error :

> The package comic_dl.UWP_2.1.15.0_ARM_x86_x64.appxbundle is taking a
>   long time to process. If this isn’t completed soon, try refreshing the
>   page, or remove the package and then upload it again. If you continue
>   to see this issue, contact support.

This package I tried to build from my system manually : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VVvF6IB70R2DKNUgBJcqw-HryL1LIwgo

This is what I got from App center : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o0sGKU2AKVgrcTelIoRFz7QCe8Do0WJ3

This is the Store ID : [9N81F8B5WW93](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/comanga/9n81f8b5ww93)

Can someone guide me what I might be doing wrong/missing something.

Thanks

**EDIT Update** : So, I followed the suggestion and contacted Microsoft's Team for help on this issue. After 3 months of multiple contacts, I was able to get someone to reply back and follow the case. Even they tried things on their end and I tried by deleting all the certificate files I had in my current project and tried to manually build the manifest file and then it worked. I'm not entirely sure what worked out in the end. But, you can try these things if you run into this issue.
1.) Clean your project.

2.) Delete `.vs` directory.

3.) Look for any certificate files in your project. **Back them up somewhere else** and then delete them from the project **(Don't exclude from project, just delete them entirely)**. Clean and rebuild your solution.

4.) Check if the application is already installed on your system (When you debug, VS will install your UWP app on your machine to run it). If it's installed, uninstall it completely.

5.) Make a **backup** of **your manifest file** and try to create a new manifest file.

These are the links I received from Microsoft Help:

PFN and package publisher name must match values here: [https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/`{YourAppID}`/identity](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/%60%7BYourAppID%7D%60/identity)

Update manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-create-a-package-manifest-manually

Update in VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/generate-package-manifest

If these values were pulled from test certificate, partner needs to update their test cert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is not caused by anything code related, but rather it is a problem on the Store side. I would suggest contacting the Store support, they should be able to investigate if there is something wrong with your app package or the problem is on their side.

For support go to the [official website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support), click the **Contact Us** tab and fill out the form accordingly.

The team should be able to advise even for the first error with different publisher info. If your app was always associated with the same account, there is no reason it should give you such an error message.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get through to them with this one. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue gazillion of times. It is so frustrating. That error message isn't useful at all.

Anyway - I think it is something in `Package.appxmanifest`, something in `Identity` tag.

Retrieving some necessary info from store helped me.

> `Click right` on your project -> `Publish` -> `Associate App with the Store`. This will update `Package Display Name`,`Package Name`,`Publisher ID`,`Publisher Display Name` and `Version` with correct values (within `Package.appxmanifes`).

Also be careful with version number. The last from numbers must be zero. `1.1.1.0` is fine, while `1.1.1.1` is not.