# Maintaining UWP Certificates With Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, code-signing-certificate

So, I have a few questions regarding Signing Certificates used for UWP. I've got 2 scenarios. Please guide me accordinly.

I logged into my Visual Studio Account (Normal User) in Visual Studio and I worked on a Xamarin Forms app, that had a UWP project associated as well. Now, I bought a developer account and then created app package for the same app and uploaded on the microsoft store. Everything went fine and my app was released without any issues.

Now, I after some time, I wanted to push an update to that UWP app. Now, everytime I try to upload a new update package, I get errors, which you can [read in THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870465/the-package-apppxbundle-is-taking-a-long-time-to-process-unable-to-push-updat) here.

So, I've pretty much given up on that one.
Now, I created a new app, and I have logged into my dev account in VS. I now want to create and register a new app. But, how should I go about Exporting, Importing and saving that signing certificate?

I read somewhere that VS handles this and signs the package with proper certificate of the logged in account, but that scenario isn't really working out for me.

Could some one please guide me properly what I'm missing here.

EDIT: It's not the duplicate question (at least that's what I can make of). Because, this question is asked to avoid the scenario that comes in marked question. Anyways, I never got any working/satisfactory answer in that as well.

Comment: No, I don't think it is. This is another question, which is asked to avoid the scenario mentioned in the aforementioned question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I followed [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871728/2408212) and contacted Microsoft's Team for help on this issue. After 3 months of multiple contacts, I was able to get someone to reply back and follow the case. Even they tried things on their end and I tried by deleting all the certificate files I had in my current project and tried to manually build the manifest file and then it worked. I'm not entirely sure what worked out in the end. But, you can try these things if you run into this issue.

1. Clean your project.
2. Delete `.vs` directory.
3. Look for any certificate files in your project. **Back them up somewhere else** and then delete them from the project **(Don't exclude from project, just delete them entirely)**. Clean and rebuild your solution.
4. Check if the application is already installed on your system (When you debug, VS will install your UWP app on your machine to run it). If it's installed, uninstall it completely.
5. Make a **backup** of **your manifest file** and try to create a new manifest file.

These are the links I received from Microsoft Help:

- PFN and package publisher name must match values here: [https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/`{YourAppID}`/identity](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/%60%7BYourAppID%7D%60/identity)
- Update manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-create-a-package-manifest-manually
- Update in VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/generate-package-manifest
- If these values were pulled from test certificate, partner needs to update their test cert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing

Answer (score 0):

**For the first scenario:**

> The package comic_dl.UWP_2.1.15.0_ARM_x86_x64.appxbundle is taking a long time to process.

1.You'd better upload package which type is the .msixupload or .appxupload to the Store.

2.You need to make sure that the network environment you are using has no restrictions on uploading packages.(You can try a different network to eliminate this problem or use Fiddler to track your network)

**For the second scenario:**

> But, how should I go about Exporting, Importing and saving that signing certificate?

For your new app submission, there is no need to export or import the sign certificate, you should clean your app, then associate it with the new app name(VS will  update a new certificate for publishing ) and rebuild the app, then create App package.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning scenarios about the first issue. But, that's not something I was aiming in this question because then this will be a duplicate question. But, about the network thing, I've tried that. Still didn't work.

Comment: For your second scenario,did you re-associate the app and then package it to upload to the Store? Under normal circumstances, there is no need to export or import the sign certificate.

Comment: Yep. Did that 2 time. I can even see that the information matches in the appmanifest (or whichever file was that holds the author info). The info matches with the one shown in the Dashboard in my Dev account for the app.

Comment: Did you upload the package which type is .msixupload or .appxupload in the dashboard?

Comment: .appxupload, yes.

Comment: What are the details of the error you encountered in publishing the new app?

Comment: `The package comic_dl.UWP_2.1.15.0_ARM_x86_x64.appxbundle is taking a long time to process. If this isn’t completed soon, try refreshing the page, or remove the package and then upload it again. If you continue to see this issue, contact support.`.... That's all I get.

Comment: From my inspection and testing, I've seen that my Visual Studio isn't aligning the signing certificate properly. I posted for that issue on Xamarin Forums as well : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/389857/#Comment_389857 .

Comment: And yes, I've updated my Visual Studio, I have even Re-logged in to update the certificate.

Comment: After this problem, have you ever tried to upload the package of a test app in dashboard?

Comment: I've tried to push updated package again and again after 1 week. Same issue.

Comment: Depending on what you've described, this could be a problem with your dashboard, you could ask the help on the [Support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support).

Comment: Yeah, I tried dropping email 2 times. 1 time I got the reply stating to re-open the ticket and still waiting for reply for the second email... been a month now, I guess.

Comment: For your issue， the [Support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) is the only channel to handle it, you may need continue to contact them.